# JBoss crashes, no errors in logs

Tags: java, jboss, crash

The problem: our production JBoss server has suddenly stopped responding. `service jboss status` was returning `Jboss crashed`. We restarted the server and began to investigate, but... there was not much evidence.

No errors in server log (the log just suddenly stops). No `hs_err_<pid>.log`. GC logs shows unusually high memory consumption right before the crash though, both for JBoss and Tomcat which is running on the same server (application on Tomcat sends requests to the app on JBoss). Right before the crash total heap usage on JBoss was 97,7% (normally it was somewhere around 85%). But there was no heap dump (`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` is enabled).

**Not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions how to debug this issue?**

Versions info:

```
JBoss 4.0.4 ga
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```